# Python 3.6+ Conventions for fetching paginated data

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous

I find myself often encountering a use case where I need to fetch paginated data, where I need *all* of the data. Currently I use something similar to below to handle these cases:

```py
def fetch_paginated_data(api_base, query, good_citizen_rate):    
    encoded = urllib.parse.quote(query.encode('utf-8'))
    initial = f'{api_base}?q={encoded}'
    payload = {
        'has_more': True,
        'next_page': initial
    }

    storage = []

    while payload['has_more']:
        response = requests.get(payload['next_page'])
        if response.status_code != 200:
            raise ValueError('Status not 200')
            payload['has_more'] = False
            return

        data = response.json()
        if (data and data['data']):
            storage.extend(data['data'])

        payload['has_more'] = data['has_more']
        if 'next_page' in data:
            payload['next_page'] = data['next_page']
        time.sleep(good_citizen_rate)
    return storage
```

My question is how could I better make this convention more reusable? Should I use `async` / `await`? `yield` pages? Add a callback to transform the data prior to adding it to the collection variable?

Comment: What would be the response of `requests.get(payload['next_page'])` if there is no next page? And why do you need `time.sleep(good_citizen_rate)`?

Comment: @ades that is why there is a `has_more` from the apis I often use. `time.sleep(good_citizen_rate)` is to follow the providers of these apis guidelines

Comment: It seems that the statement `payload['has_more'] = False` has no effect, because it is written **after** `raise` (also the `return`). And it seems not only related to 3.6+ (except for the f-string feature you're using, so this is only a side comment).

Answer (score 3):

You should let the `requests` module do the urlencoding for you. It can take a [dictionary of parameters](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls) and do it right.

Instead of having a variable around which you check in your `while` condition, I would prefer a `while True` and an explicit `break` here. The loop is small enough that this makes it more readable IMO.

I would indeed use `yield`, or rather `yield from` here, in order to flatten the response. This means that the next page is only fetched when you have consumed the previous data. If you need to, you could also make it asynchronously using [`aiohttp`](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/), have a look at [this question of mine](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/237253/98493) which used it or the documentation I linked.

You can also use [`response.raise_for_status`](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.Response.raise_for_status) to raise an exception if the status code is not 2XX. Note that any code after a `raise` is not accessible, so your `payload['has_more'] = False` and `return` will never run (unless you run it in a debugger or something).

Python has an official style-guide, [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), which you are following (nice!). One thing it does not recommend but I would nevertheless encourage you to do is not using unnecessary parenthesis in `if` statements. Python is not C.

```
def fetch_paginated_data(url, query, timeout=0):    
    params = {"q": query}
    while True:
        response = requests.get(url, params=params)
        response.raise_for_status()
        data = response.json()
        if data and data['data']:
            yield from data['data']
        if not data['has_more']:
            break
        url = data['next_page']
        time.sleep(timeout)
```

Here I left the interface as is. If you are free to change it, I would consider taking `params` directly as an argument or even collect all keyword arguments (except for the timeout, which I also gave a defualt value) directly into a dictionary with `**params`. The latter would give you the very nice interface:

```
data = fetch_paginated_data("example.com", q="FooBar", timeout=3)
```

Instead of `if data and data['data']:` you could also just use a `try..except` block. This will be slightly more performant if the response usually has this key:

```
try:
    yield from data['data']
except (KeyError, TypeError):  # for dict, list
    pass
```

You should definitely add a [`docstring`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) describing what this function does. Especially your naming the timeout a rate can be confusing for other people reading your code, or yourself in half a year.

Answer (score 0):

Without the other code that calls that function is difficutl to say if you need async operations or not, on the other hand here are some suggestions to make your code more pythonic.

```
payload = {
    'has_more': True,
    'next_page': initial
}
```

Change to

```
has_more = True
next_page = initial
```

Your code

```
while payload['has_more']:
    response = requests.get(payload['next_page'])
    if response.status_code != 200:
        raise ValueError('Status not 200')
        payload['has_more'] = False
        return
```

Change to

```
while has_more:
    response = requests.get(payload['next_page'])
    if response.status_code != 200:
        raise ValueError('Status not 200')
```

Your code

```
    payload['has_more'] = data['has_more']
```

Change to

```
    has_more = data['has_more']
```

Sorry if I forget more changes.